# insert hosts in check via for loop

Tags: bash, curl, check-mk

following problem:

we have a file called "file.conf"

```
192.168.30.1|192.168.30.1|os
_gateway|192.168.30.2|Linux 2.6.18 - 2.6.22
...
```

first is the hostname second is the ipv4

now we have a script where he should automaticaly insert the hosts and ip's via automated user from checkMK

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=filename
source $FILE

for i in ${FILE}
do

HOSTNAME=$(cat $i | cut -d '|' -f1)
IP=$(cat $i | cut -d '|' -f2)

curl "http://checkmkadress/check_mk/host&user" -d 'request={"hostname":"'"$HOSTNAME"'","folder":"ansible","attributes":{"ipaddress":"'"$IP"'","site":"sitename","tag_agent":"cmk-agent"}}'


done
```

but if we do it like that we get the following error cause he try's to put in every host in host and every ip in ip without going through all lines

```
{"result": "Check_MK exception: Failed to parse JSON request: '{\"hostname\":\"allhostnames":{\"ipaddress\":all_ips\",\"site\":\"sitename\",\"tag_agent\":\"cmk-agent\"}}': Invalid control character at: line 1 column 26 (char 25)", "result_code": 1}
```

how can we make the curl script go through each line to get host and ip individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you already done, try in this way.

```
FILE="filename"
source $FILE

while read line
do

    HOSTNAME=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f1)
    IP=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f2)

    #your curl command here

done <$FILE
```

OR, which I prefer

```
while IFS='|' read -r host ip description
do 
   #your curl command here
   echo "$host : $ip : $description"
done <$FILE
```